# Read image files and display it on SVG issues (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, svg, filesystems, blob, filereader

I have been playing with the FileSystem API for JavaScript,
I already succeeded at store the file to the file storage provided by the API,

I tried to read the file that was stored, which is a JPG image,
and read it using the `FileReader` with the `readAsDataURL` method,
so I can display it in the SVG using the `xlink:href` attribute,

But the image(SVG image) won't display the image (only blank),
when I use the "Inspect Element" provided by Chrome,
I saw the `xlink:href` attribute is filled with this value:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFZOZXREaXNwbGF5U3lzdGVtcy5TaGFyZWQsIFZlcnNpb249NC4xLjQ2OTUuMTY5NDMsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAUBAAAAME5ldERpc3BsYXlTeXN0ZW1zLlN5bmNocm9uaXphdGlvbi5SZW1vdGVGaWxlRGF0YQQAAAAPQ3JlYXRpb25UaW1lVXRjEExhc3RXcml0ZVRpbWVVdGMEU2l6ZQxSZWxhdGl2ZVBhdGgAAAABDQ0JAgAAAKrTBCT9is9IV01fnlvSy0h16AwAAAAAAAYDAAAACkRlc2VydC5qcGcLAA ..."
```

(the rest is a very long sequence of `A`'s)

I don't know what is wrong,

Here is the code I use to read the file and display the element:

```
var element; 
element= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
element.setAttribute("id", "img1");
element.setAttribute("x", "30");
element.setAttribute("y", "250");
element.setAttribute("width", "150");
element.setAttribute("height", "150");

fs.root.getFile("Desert.jpg", {}, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        element.setAttribute("xlink:href", e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }, FileExceptions);
},FileExceptions); //error callback

return element;
```

The raw string uri before encoded with `btoa()`:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFZOZXREaXNwbGF5U3lzdGVtcy5TaGFyZWQsIFZlcnNpb249NC4xLjQ2OTUuMTY5NDMsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAUBAAAAME5ldERpc3BsYXlTeXN0ZW1zLlN5bmNocm9uaXphdGlvbi5SZW1vdGVGaWxlRGF0YQQAAAAPQ3JlYXRpb25UaW1lVXRjEExhc3RXcml0ZVRpbWVVdGMEU2l6ZQxSZWxhdGl2ZVBhdGgAAAABDQ0JAgAAAKrTBCT9is9IV01fnlvSy0h16AwAAAAAAAYDAAAACkRlc2VydC5qcGcLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

where the `...` indicates that the sequence of `A`'s is shortened because it was too long.

This is the code for the inserting/creating the file to the file system that I insert in the beginning:

```
function InsertFile(fileName: string, blob:Blob) {
    fs.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true /*exclusive: true*/ }, function (fileEntry) { 
        //change the exclusive to true, this is for debugging only
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) { InfoLog("Write Completed"); };
        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) { InfoLog("Write Failed \r\n" + e.toString()); };
        fileWriter.write(blob);
        },FileExceptions);
    }, FileExceptions);
}
```

the fileName contains the "Desert.jpg"
I already checked it and it's true
I got the blob from the server,

Comment: can you post the source of the entire svg element?

Comment: Does it load up in other browsers?

Comment: No it won't load.. and I tried to change the element to the plain HTML img, and it display a broken image somehow..

Comment: I guess that for html img you should use `src` attribute instead of `xlink:href`

Comment: Yes, when I change the svg image to HTML img I change the xlink:href to src, but still display a broken image

Comment: Something is wrong with the encoding, what are you using to encode the image to base64?

Comment: Didn't use any encoding..do you know a way to do that?

Comment: I just used the window.btoa() method, but still broken image

Comment: added, edited in the question

Comment: It looks like Desert.jpg was stored incorrectly into the FileSystem API, but without having that part of the code it's impossible to debug. Good luck.

Comment: @Duopixel added the code for creating the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solved..apparently there's nothing wrong with the Blob or the code of the script,
and the file is actually saved correctly in the file system storage API of HTML5,

the problem was that the Blob was indeed corrupted because it was the server (in .net) that is failed to convert the file to byte() to be sent to the client(html5),
after I change the conversion method in the server, the image can be loaded properly and correctly